# How to use google calendar API to access calendar's data and analyze social,meeting and school work percentage time?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, data-analysis

We are thinking about analyzing people's social,meeting,school work time and its' corresponding percentage based on their personal schedule. Here we assume that personal calendar has been divided into different categories like social, meeting and there are no overlap in schedule.

Anyone can give me more general information about how to start the google calendar authentication process(using OAuth?), how can we get access to personal calendar info as well as what API I can use? As well as what tools we can use to analyze data? We are expecting to grab the info from google calendar, do the analysis and then display on our website.

We are attending a School Hackathon and really passionate to build something out.
Any suggestions, comments and info will be helpful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to use JavaScript, check out the [Getting Started example](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js).
In that example, you'll see a request made to Google Plus:

```
var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
    'userId': 'me'
});
```

To make requests to Google's API, you'll need to get a developer key. You'll need [OAuth 2.0 credentials](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication) to read private user data. That will let you ask for permission to access the user's calendar like so:
[image]

Once you have that key, you can make requests to Calendar. Try out those requests (e.g. calendar.events.list) at the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/).

P.S. That's great that you're getting involved in a hackathon and preparing :)

Answer (score 0):

Google calendar API can be used to access  the information from the calendar like add events,edit or delete the events and retrieve the  calendar information. Below are the steps on how to access calendar API:

1. Set up a client library. Calendar API supports Java,python,Ruby,.net
2. Configure your app.

   a.Register your app in the [Google developers console](https://console.developers.google.com/project).Then it provides the information about client ID and client secret. Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth) for detailed information.

   b.In the sidebar on the left of the developers console, expand APIs & auth. Next, click APIs. In the list of APIs, make sure the status is ON for the Google Calendar API.

3.Define the scopes. When your application needs access to user data, it asks Google for a particular scope of access.
Google calendar scopes are:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar --- for read/write access to Calendars
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly-- read-only access to Calendars

4.Google displays a consent screen to the user, asking them to authorize your application to request some of their data. When user clicks on ACCEPT, then Google gives your application a access token(which lives only for an hr).
5.Your application requests user data, attaching the access token to the request.
If Google determines that your request and the token are valid, it returns the requested data.
6.Once the access token expires then you can use the refresh token(Use offline access for this). Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) for the detailed information on Oauth.
7.Then the application is ready to access the google calendar API.
8.Also,you can check on [Ouath playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to check on how Oauth and API's work.

9.Calendar API [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/).

Hope this information helps you.